# QML Listview - how to get space between header and first list item

Tags: listview, qml

I use the same delegate for the header as for the items of a listview.

How do I get a free space above the header (red arrow) and between the header and the first list entry (blue arrow)?

The list entries themselves get a free space through the spacing property of the listview.

[image]

List qml:

```
ColumnLayout { anchors.fill: parent;
        ListView { Layout.fillWidth: true;  Layout.fillHeight: true; 
            model: cp_screen.selectlistModel
            currentIndex: cp_screen.selectlistIndex
            onCurrentIndexChanged: { console.log("currentIndex changed") }
            header: SelectlistDelegate { p_height: p_listheight; p_width: list.width; p_index: -1; p_text1: cp_screen.getListHeaderText(); p_icon: cp_screen.getListHeaderIcon(); p_isHeader: true }
            delegate: SelectlistDelegate { p_height: p_listheight; p_width: list.width; p_index: index; p_text1: r_text1; p_text2: r_text2; p_icon: r_icon; p_isHeader: false }
            spacing: p_listspacing
        }
    }
```

ListDelegate qml:

```
Item { id: root
    property real p_height
    property real p_width
    property int p_index
    property string p_text1
    property string p_text2
    property string p_text3
    property string p_icon
    property bool p_isHeader
    property bool p_isSelected: root.ListView.view.currentIndex == p_index
    property string p_color: cp_config.getColor(p_isHeader ? Colors.ListItemDisabled : (p_isSelected ? Colors.ListItemSelected : Colors.ListItemDefault))
    width: p_width
    height: p_height
  
    Rectangle { height: p_height; width: p_width; color: p_color;  
        RowLayout { anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter;
            Image { Layout.leftMargin: 10; sourceSize.height: p_height * 0.5; source: "image://iconprovider/" + p_icon }
            Label { Layout.leftMargin: 20; text: p_text1 }
            Label { Layout.leftMargin: 20; text: p_text2 }
        }
        MouseArea{ enabled: !p_isHeader; anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: { root.ListView.view.currentIndex = p_index; } } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend changing your header to be an Item that contains your delegate but is taller so it adds the space that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented @JarMan's suggestion in implementing a different delegate for the `header` that has the space.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { ico: "userkey.svg"; txt: "?" }
            ListElement { ico: "key.svg"; txt: "0000" }
        }
        currentIndex: 0
        spacing: 5
        header: ColumnLayout {
            width: ListView.view.width
            ItemDelegate {
                id: itemDelegate
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                background: Rectangle { color: "#ccc" }
                text: "Anlegen"
                icon.source: "user.svg"
            }
            Item {
            }
        }
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            property ListView listView: ListView.view
            property bool isCurrentItem: ListView.isCurrentItem
            width: listView.width
            background: Rectangle {
                color: isCurrentItem && "cyan"
                || (index & 1) && "#eee"
                || "#ccc"
            }
            text: txt
            icon.source: ico
            onClicked: listView.currentIndex = index
        }
    }
}

// key.svg: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/key-32.svg
// userkey.svg: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/user-key-32.svg
// user.svg: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/user-32.svg
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Sorry for late response - thanks very much, great solution exactly what I was looking for